# Why is the scapy installation failing on Mac?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, scapy

When I try installing scapy on Mac, I get this error:

```
  Collecting scapy
  Downloading scapy-2.3.1.zip (1.1MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.1MB 436kB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "/private/tmp/pip-build-f7vu4fsp/scapy/setup.py", line 35
        os.chmod(fname,0755)
                          ^
    SyntaxError: invalid token

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-f7vu4fsp/scapy
```

I tried using `pip install scapy` and `pip3 install scapy`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To install scapy for python3, you have to run `pip3 install scapy-python3`. Just `pip3 install scapy` will install old 2.x version, which is not python3 compatible.